# Advanced Typescript inference using keyof

Tags: typescript

So we are developing a CMS for Firestore and have created a schema system in Typescript. Users can define schemas and the data is fetch from the database with the specified schema properties.

The basic types we use:

```
export interface EntitySchema {
    properties: Record<string, any>;
}

interface Entity<S extends EntitySchema> {
    values: {
        [K in keyof S["properties"]]: any
    }
}
```

So we have the `EntitySchema` the developer defines, and the Entity which are the objects he gets back when fetching from the database. I include a sample method that populates the values defined in the schema:

```
function getEntity<S extends EntitySchema>(
    schema: S
): Entity<S> {
    return {
        values: Object.keys(schema.properties)
            .map((key) => ({ [key]: undefined }))
            .reduce((a: any, b: any) => ({ ...a, ...b }), {})
    };
}
```

The problem I am facing is that Typescript is not inferring properly the keys from the schema in the entity:

```
const sampleSchema: EntitySchema = {
    properties: {
        name: "Name"
    }
};

const entityA: Entity<typeof sampleSchema> = getEntity(sampleSchema);
const shouldFail = entityA.values.notExistingProperty; // doesn't fail

// also creating the entity directly doesn't work as expected
const entityB: Entity<typeof sampleSchema> = {
    values: {
        name: "aaa", // this is ok
        shouldFailToo: "bbb" // doesn't fail
    }
};
```

Either if I use the simulated DB method or initialise the Entity with a supplied schema directly, the `values` field in the Entity is just treated as a `Record<string, any>` and the keys of the schema are ignored. I feel I am missing something here. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to preserve type information using a record, thanks to the lead of Zbigniew Zagórski :)

```
export interface EntitySchema {
    properties: Record<string, any>;
}

interface Entity<S extends EntitySchema> {
    values: Record<Extract<keyof S["properties"], string>, any>
}

// simulate getting an entity from a db with a schema
function getEntity<S extends EntitySchema>(
    schema: S
): Entity<S> {
    return {
        values: Object.keys(schema.properties)
            .map((key) => ({ [key]: undefined }))
            .reduce((a: any, b: any) => ({ ...a, ...b }), {})
    };
}

const schema = {
    properties: {
        name: "Name",
        ppp: "a"
    }
};
const entity = getEntity(schema);
const ok = entity.values.name;
const shouldFail = entity.values.notExistingProperty; // fails
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Record<string,any>` erases all the type information that typescript would otherwise infer, if you would use template parameter there.

You must somehow name type that contain properties of your document/schema. I would propose something like this:

```js
export interface EntitySchema<T> {
    properties: T
}
```

Now, you build all the code around `T` which is your "schema properties definition":

```js
interface Entity<T> {
    values: {
        [K in keyof T]: any
    }
}
function getEntity<T>(
    schema: EntitySchema<T>
): Entity<T> {
    return {
        values: Object.keys(schema.properties)
            .map((key) => ({ [key]: undefined }))
            .reduce((a: any, b: any) => ({ ...a, ...b }), {})
    };
}
```

Now, you can use it, by defining interface that contains names of allowed properties (popssibly with metadata):

```js
interface SampleModel {
    name: string;
}
const sampleSchema: EntitySchema<SampleModel> = {
    properties: {
        name: "Name"
    }
};
```

And now TS is properly type-checking your code:

```js
const entityA: Entity<SampleModel> = getEntity(sampleSchema);
const shouldFail = entityA.values.notExistingProperty; // FAILS :)

// also creating the entity directly doesn't work as expected
const entityB: Entity<SampleModel> = {
    values: {
        name: "aaa", // this is ok
        shouldFailToo: "bbb" // FAILS
    }
};
```

I've changed you model a little, here is [TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=39&pc=3#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAgJYDs4hgMwIYGMQICiaScAngMq4AWIAttgDwAqAfAgN7AI8IQxQIGOEhABnAFwJmAbmABfYMFToseAsRHkW7LrwQA3bABsAruKl79vANoBpZCgQBrEGSiZpAXSnYUZbl5FRUxTFFwRKCcAcxA4TVIyHQAKQJ4xGnpsKQTyKloGHWAAShySbTZONIQYONMYJytrQxNzSQQAeQAjACsQCIA6VzIxZIyC7AH%20QWFRMWLq5p4Bhghk5OHihABedmSOBBthnwQwgBMQTFQQM4R5YoWl6wHas9N8deyEPzIAGgQur5-Ftdgh9ggBpDsP9IQMundiv8OPdqvI5IplGgMDh8AgKNg6BBjCAALJQC7GKo8FAEkBSMRwGCoaLo4C4KIMhBiAlEkD5LJlLSUTKFfGE4lkinsbZU3jTITwOaWRa8Gl0OkIABEADlaZrUQo5GyOYgQOUyABBQWJRhi3mSkDGaUIWLxc1jHnE-kMYpydkoTliahQUzGM4AMWwSEpMrNQotAyMZnEAxQUHiYCQDOZAAUBAryDIEAB6YsIM5QcQoADkiBw0aUpe%20xjEUAQuFq2BEKGiCDgtAQccS5aQtQixjI5crYhriAA7rBnN8xIPIP10GdjQHTeaAELW7R2iXkx3OpotZPtc-6NUazXYB%20a-5N-tZ5ArqDOFXpYOhiNR4xmCgKApE1LpwM1EsywrKtawQetjANNEgA)

Comment: Wow thanks a lot!! This definitely points me in the right direction!
The only issue I have is that I really need the schema properties to have a record shape.
I have simplified the example but the generic you call <T> needs to be a Record<string, Property>, being Property another interface that looks like:
```
interface Property {
    type: "string" | "number"
   ...
}
```